# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' when change in Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have done Routing in my routeConfig file as below.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Search",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{department}/{name}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Result",name =UrlParameter.Optional}
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I want only name parameter should be optional, so made this this by writing

```
name =UrlParameter.Optional
```

But now when I click on this link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditEmployee", new { id = item.Id })
```

It gives me exception "`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id'`"

Case 1: 
but when I do this,

```
defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Result"}
```

Removing name optional, It works fine.

case 2: 
When I do this

```
defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Result", department =UrlParameter.Optional, name=UrlParameter.Optional}
```

making both parameter optional, also works fine , but now Url generating for Edit is as follow

```
http://localhost:12190/Home/EditEmployee?id=1
```

but I want clean URL like this
`http://localhost:12190/Home/EditEmployee/1`.

So How can get both,only name parameter optional and also a clean URL.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two routes and it seems like you mixed them in your mind. The path you provided (`http://localhost:12190/Home/EditEmployee?id=1`) refers to the second route while *department* and *name* parameters - to the first one.

Maybe you need to comment the first route and try to get everything working with your set of parameters - *action* and *id*. Also you can try to use attribute routing to specify routes to your controllers and actions